# left_join on a nested list

Tags: r, dplyr, merge, left-join

I have a nested df `x` and an unnested df `y`.

How can I join these two together so that the final output is a a single row with the `id` and `val` columns from `x` and a new column for each of the respective `num` values in order of appearance, `num_1`, `num_2` ...?

```r
library(tidyverse)

x <- tibble(id = list(letters[1:6]), val = 13)
x

#> # A tibble: 1 x 2
#>   id          val
#>   <list>    <dbl>
#> 1 <chr [6]>    13

y <- tibble(id = letters[1:6], num = rnorm(6))
y

#> # A tibble: 6 x 2
#>   id       num
#>   <chr>  <dbl>
#> 1 a      0.532
#> 2 b     -0.106
#> 3 c     -0.105
#> 4 d      0.973
#> 5 e     -0.825
#> 6 f     -0.951

map2(x, y, left_join, by = 'id')
```

> Error in UseMethod("left_join"): no applicable method for 'left_join' applied to an object of class "list"

<sup>Created on 2020-08-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

**Edit:** I'm looking for something loosely like this while still maintaining the ID column.

```r
x %>% 
  unnest(id) %>% 
  left_join(y) %>% 
  mutate(n = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = -id,
              values_from = num,
              names_from = n)

#> Joining, by = "id"
#> # A tibble: 1 x 7
#>     val   `1`    `2`    `3`     `4`   `5`   `6`
#>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1    13  1.28 -0.387 -0.438 -0.0826 0.164 -1.24
```

Comment: Could you provide your expected output?

Comment: why is `id` a `list` in `x`

Comment: I can unnest x, but because the real data has a lot of variables I've been having trouble pivoting them back into shape. This seemed like an easier question, considering how I wanted all of the output to be numbered

Comment: @DarrenTsai I tried my best to explain the expected output in the text, is that ok to work with?

Comment: I think it would be great if you could create a df like you did for `x` and `y` for your expected output

Comment: @DarrenTsai  I added a new part to the question containing the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing with your work, you can try the following.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

x %>% 
  unnest(id) %>% 
  left_join(y, by = "id") %>% 
  mutate(name = row_number(), id = list(id)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(values_from = num, names_glue = "num_{name}")

# # A tibble: 1 x 8
#   id          val num_1  num_2  num_3   num_4 num_5 num_6
#   <list>    <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 <chr [6]>    13  1.28 -0.387 -0.438 -0.0826 0.164 -1.24
```

or

```
x %>%
  mutate(num = map(id, ~ tibble::deframe(y) %>% .[match(names(.), .x)] %>% unname)) %>%
  unnest_wider(num, names_sep = "_")

# # A tibble: 1 x 8
#   id          val num_1  num_2  num_3   num_4 num_5 num_6
#   <list>    <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 <chr [6]>    13  1.28 -0.387 -0.438 -0.0826 0.164 -1.24
```

***Description of the second solution***

`deframe()` in `tibble` transforms a two-column `data.frame` to a named vector, the first column is converted to vector names and the second one is converted to vector values. `deframe(y) %>% .[match(names(.), .x)]` is equivalent to `deframe(y)[match(names(deframe(y)), .x)]`. The `deframe(y)` part appears twice, so I move it to the front of a pipe and use the `.` symbol to represent it behind the pipe. This line is to match the position of `id` columns of both data and reorder `num` column of `y`.

Comment: Thanks @Darren Tsai, I will accept. Would you mind briefly describing what the `deframe(y) %>% .[match(names(.), .x)] %>% unname` is doing?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your `y` you're not going to have multiple columns but adjusting the example a little, is this what you were aiming for?

```
x <- tibble(id = list(letters[1:6]), val = 13)
y <- tibble(id = rep(letters[1:6],2), num = rnorm(12), 
            name = paste0("num_", rep(1:2, each = 6)))

map_dfr(x$id[[1]], ~tibble(id = .x, val = x$val)) %>% 
  left_join(
    pivot_wider(y, names_from = name, values_from = num)
  )

#> Joining, by = "id"
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#>   id      val   num_1  num_2
#>   <chr> <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1 a        13  0.609   1.97 
#> 2 b        13  0.956  -1.84 
#> 3 c        13  0.425   0.297
#> 4 d        13  0.0379 -0.784
#> 5 e        13 -0.532  -0.769
#> 6 f        13  0.538  -1.10
```

Comment: No I'd like to return a single row, where the values of y are labelled 1 through 6